iptraf shows amazing TCP flow traffic because of nfs
I have a diskless server with Fedora36.
My server sends the bootloader and kernel using tftp and the clients boot with them. After booting, the clients share the same directory as a root directory from the server, i.e. 10.100.0.1:/tftpboot/nfsroot/, using nfs.
Here, the problem occurs. Even if I don't do anything, just boot them up, they transmit packets continuously. iptraf-ng shows me that TCP flow rate exceeds 100kbps.
My other servers which are built the same way do not show this result. The result of iptraf-ng on the other servers shows TCP flow rate 0kbps.
Can you help me? Why does my newly built server transmit the packets?
